# How to specify a whitelist for HTTP basic authentication (to except certain paths from requiring a password)?

Tags: apache

Here's the essential part of my current configuration, where I protect my entire website using HTTP basic authentication:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Area"

    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords_file

    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I want to except certain paths so they are publicly available, specifically `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, `manifest.json`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following configuration block after the existing `Location` one will except the specified paths from requiring a password:

```
<Location ~ "^/favicon\.ico$|^/manifest\.json$|^/robots\.txt$">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

This one uses a single regex matching string for all files, but you could also specify each of them individually, one at a time, without using regex:

```
<Location "/favicon.ico">
    Require all granted
</Location>

<Location "/manifest.json">
    Require all granted
</Location>

<Location "/robots.txt">
    Require all granted
</Location>
```